# Show image after X para - center aligned

Tags: functions

I am using this code in wordpress functions.php to display featured image after 1st para.

The problem is: Image is showing left-aligned. I want it to be center aligned..

Please modify this code so I can display the image in the centre of post?

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'insert_featured_image', 20 );

function insert_featured_image( $content ) {

    $content = preg_replace( "/<\/p>/", "</p>" . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'post-single'), $content, 1 );

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Hello! Any answer you get here will explain how or why, but not copy paste answers without understanding or explanation. Could you note centre align the image using CSS?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work. Just FYI, questions asking for code to be written are not terribly popular with the community because they rarely act as good lessons for others to learn from.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell WordPress about the centre aligned HTML or style you wish to use.

I would do this:

```
 $content = preg_replace( "/<\/p>/", "</p><div style='margin:auto;textalign:center;'>" . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'post-single') . "</div>", $content, 1 );
```

or better yet:

```
 $content = preg_replace( "/<\/p>/", "</p><div class='center'>" . get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, 'post-single') . "</div>", $content, 1 );
```

You would need to make sure the class exists in your CSS or add one to do the centering.

Comment: Thanks it worked.

Comment: @samjoezzy, I am glad I was able to help. If your question has been completely covered t your satisfction consider marking an answer as the solution.